# gcc Hangs trying to compile with -O2 optimisation

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

I was trying to compile my project today, I have never had any trouble compiling this project before on multiple platforms, but trying on Mac OS X using g++ (4.2.1) in release mode (which uses the -O2 optimisation flag) caused the compilation to get stuck forever on the same file. Playing around with the code, I narrowed the problems down to essentially this code:

```
void MyClass::SendBigMessage()
{
    int Offset = 0;
    PackByteArrayIntoMessage(SomeDataArray1, SomeDataArray1Size, Offset);
    PackByteArrayIntoMessage(SomeDataArray2, SomeDataArray2Size, Offset);
    // ...snip
    PackByteArrayIntoMessage(SomeDataArray9, SomeDataArray9Size, Offset);
    PackByteArrayIntoMessage(SomeDataArray10, SomeDataArray10Size, Offset);

    SendMessage(Message);
}

void MyClass::PackByteArrayIntoMessage(unsigned char *ByteArray, int Size, int &Offset)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        Message.SetByteAtOffset(ByteArray[i], Offset++);
    }
}
```

Commenting out the body of the `PackByteArrayIntoMessage` means the file compiles without problem. Also, commenting out all of the calls to `PackByteArrayIntoMessage`, but leaving the body of the function commented in, means the file compiles without problem. When I start commenting in more calls to it, the compile time seems to get exponentially longer, until, with about 10 sequential calls to it, it seems to hang compiling the file forever.

I guessed gcc was trying to do some clever optimisations, so I played around with the `PackByteArrayIntoMessage` until it started compiling again, this implementation worked fine:

```
void MyClass::PackByteArrayIntoMessage(unsigned char *ByteArray, int Size, int &Offset)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        Message.SetByteAtOffset(ByteArray[i], Offset + i);
    }
    Offset = Offset + Size;
}
```

I can only assume this is a bug in gcc 4.2.1, as compiling with gcc 4.4.0 using -O2 on Linux works fine with no code modifications.

So my question is, what exactly is the compiler trying to do that causes the hanging problem? I looked through the release notes of some gcc versions but I couldn't find anything referencing this particular issue. Also, is there a way to mark code segments to make sure they are not optimised?

Comment: By the way: your calls contain two parameters, but the function requires three parameters.

Comment: If it's a bug it might not translate into something listed in the "change list". It's quite possibly an issue buried deep in the optimization code of the compiler somewhere.

Comment: As an aside, the gcc-4.2.1 distributed with Xcode / command line tools is both old, and an Apple-specific composite of GCC and LLVM, held together with glue and string. You should consider using Clang, or a recent port of, say, gcc-4.8.1.

Comment: @BrettHale - I'd rather use Clang, or you know, a compiler that isn't 6 years old, but my project relies on Qt4.8, and Clang is not officially supported, unless I move to Qt5.

Comment: No-one is likely to fix the bug in GCC 4.2.1; GCC 4.4 is no longer supported by the GCC developers either (4.7.x is the oldest release they work on).  So, you are caught between a rock and a hard place — upgrading the compiler seems necessary, and if that means upgrading to Qt5, so be it?  Or are there political/legal issues with Qt5 vs Qt4.8 that I'm unaware of?  But if it won't work with the compiler/code combination, something is going to have to change, and the old compiler is less likely to change than your code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - The bug has been fixed in GCC, as using later versions of it compiles fine. I am sticking to Qt4.8 as that is what we have been using on the project for the last 2 years, so it is well tested. For new projects we are using Qt5 and will be using Clang on Mac OS X. For the legacy project, my solution is to re-factor the code as in my question

Comment: Looking at produced assembly at no-opt and O2 would be helpful

Comment: It is very stange that gcc 7 failed to build lua sources. It just hangs… And yes, problem occur on -O2 optimisation.

Comment: gcc-4.2.1 that comes with XCode should never, ever be used for any purpose. It's that simple. If you need gcc, install gcc. If you need clang, install clang.